# Android Image still saving even User permission denied for image

Tags: java, android, screenshot, android-permissions, user-permissions

With reference to title, I have a small snippet for an Android app, in which the user clicks on a button to take a screenshot. I have used the user permission `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` instead of `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE | READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

While testing the above-mentioned part of the app, I got two scenarios.

The only Permission required in the Program is to store(write) the screenshot taken into the folder and then read it for sharing.

1. When the app opens the first time and permissions are denied

In this case, User has denied permission to the app but on clicking the button for taking a screenshot, the app is able to save the image to the internal storage.

2. When the user has allowed the permission but later denied it by going to the app setting (App info)

In this case, the user is not asked again for permission and the app is able to save the image to internal storage though permission has been denied.

Permmission Android Manifest -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

Asking for permission -

```
public void requestPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,required_permission[0]) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permission_allowed = true;
    } else {
        required_permission_launcher_storage_image.launch(required_permission[0]);
        permission_allowed = false;
    }

}

private ActivityResultLauncher<String>required_permission_launcher_storage_image = 
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
                isGranted ->{
                    if (isGranted) {
                        permission_allowed = true;
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Image Storage Permission Granted",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        permission_allowed = false;
                    }
                });
```

Activity code -

```
boolean is_storage_image_permitted = false;

    String[] required_permission = new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityScreenshotTestingBinding binding = ActivityScreenshotTestingBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        ConstraintLayout layout = binding.activityScreenshotTesting;//activitylayout

        if (!permission_allowed) {
            requestPermissions();
        }


        binding.buttonTakeScreenshot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(ScreenshotTesting.this, "ScreenShoot BUtton Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bitmap screenshot = captureScreenShot(layout);//function for screenshot
              
            }
        });
```

Where I am getting wrong?
Everything is working smoothly, but the image is saved without user permission.
If the app is published like this, it will violate privacy and Google may suspend the App.

Comment: `"Image Storage Permission Granted",` Wrong. You got permission to read. Not to store/write.

Comment: `When app open first time and permissions is denied` Which permission? Start naming it.

Comment: `image is save without user permission. I` What is a user permission?

Comment: `if app publish like this it will violate the privacy and Google may suspend the App.` ???? Unclear what would be violated. Please elaborate.

Comment: @blackapps 1. I want to have both read and write permission.                                      2. I asked user for `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` permission as coded in manifest                                              3. When user denied the `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` permission why screenshot is taken by app and store in folder.                                                                                                   4. Here app is stroing image wihtout even when user denied permssion to do so. Is this not violation of user data privacy?

Comment: No. Why do you think it is? And where is that image saved? Full path please. Android version of used device?

Comment: Please edit your post. You talk the whole time about permissions but dont name them. Name them! Write a readable post.

Comment: `taken by app and store in folder` Name the folder! And full path.

Comment: Hi app save the screenshot image in '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/TestFolder/Screenshot_2023-07-04_12_11_23.jpg'

Comment: Android version  of device where app tested is 13.

Comment: I have used `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` permission as mentioned in Manifest code in the post as well in comments

Comment: Sorry for my bad way for writing as English is my native language

Comment: In an Android 13 device your app can write files in external public Pictures directory without any permission.